# AWS SES codeigniter mail failed

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I am using the following code for sending email using my amazon ses service credentials. But messages are not getting delievered...

This is my code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'smtp_user' => '******',
    'smtp_pass' => '*********',
    'smtp_port' => 25
);

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('sender08@example.com');
$this->email->to('reciever@example.com');

$this->email->subject('Test');
$this->email->message('test');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->send();
$this->email->print_debugger();
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: any error from debugger?

Comment: no..it is not showing anyting

Answer (score 2):

To get it working I added the following lines to my config/email.php file

```
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
$config['smtp_crypto']  = 'tls';
```

Note: you need [CI 2.1.0 or later for the smtp_crypto directive](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/158882/) to work

I expect it would work by adding this to your config array too:

```
$config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'smtp_user' => '******',
    'smtp_pass' => '*********',
    'smtp_port' => 25,
    'newline'   => "\r\n",
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls'
);
```

Comment: Why $config['smtp_crypto'] it's not part of the docs?!! I've lost two hours trying to solve the problem just because of that line. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 0):

Just change email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com to ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: On applying this the following error sis coming
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1673

Answer (score 0):

i found solution : 
if you are using TLS

then in place of this 
email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

use 
tls://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

and 
add this 
   $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
where u have defined SMTP configurations .

I faced same issues solved by changing these two .

I hope this suggestions also help you guys .